# Converting VideoFrame to JPEG in Agora Flutter

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, flutter-image, tflite

I'm working on a project where I need to apply a TFLite model for each frame of the local user's video during a video call using the Agora Flutter SDK.

I came across the VideoFrameObserver in the documentation, which seems to be a promising tool for this task. Here's the code snippet I found:

```
onCaptureVideoFrame: (VideoSourceType sourceType, VideoFrame videoFrame) async {
  Uint8List yData = videoFrame.yBuffer!;
  Uint8List uData = videoFrame.uBuffer!;
  Uint8List vData = videoFrame.vBuffer!;
  int height = videoFrame.height!;
  int width = videoFrame.width!;

  // how to create JPEG image
  // ???

},
```

I've been trying to figure out how to convert the videoFrame to a JPEG image, but I haven't been successful so far. I've also checked this [issue](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Extensions/Agora-Flutter-SDK/issues/1221#issuecomment-1643466857) , but the solution provided there didn't work for me.

My question is : How to create JPEG image from yBuffer, uBuffer, vBuffer ?

Comment: _why_ do you think you need to turn the video frames into JPEG files?

Comment: because I have TFLite model for object detection that need image jpeg as input ( example --> https://github.com/tensorflow/flutter-tflite/blob/main/example/object_detection_ssd_mobilenet/lib/object_detection.dart#L60 )

Comment: you ought to look for an API that takes image data as is, not as a ***file***. if you send every frame to storage, that will slow your application down to a crawl. perhaps submit a feature request.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  I'm not planned to store image, goal is to take frame from camera convert to Uint8List ( JPEG ) and send this to the tflite model that accept Uint8List, I have already test this with other camera package --> https://github.com/Apparence-io/CamerAwesome/blob/master/example/lib/utils/mlkit_utils.dart#L4

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by **brendan-duncan** the owner of image package and it's working fine !

```
onCaptureVideoFrame: (VideoSourceType sourceType, VideoFrame videoFrame) async {
  final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final filePath = '${directory.path}/frame.jpeg';
  int height = videoFrame.height!;
  int width = videoFrame.width!;
  final img = Image(width: width, height: height);
  final yData = videoFrame.yBuffer!;
  final uData = videoFrame.uBuffer!;
  final vData = videoFrame.vBuffer!;
  final yStride = videoFrame.yStride!;
  final uStride = videoFrame.uStride!;
  final vStride = videoFrame.vStride!;
          
  for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    var y2 = y ~/ 2;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        var x2 = x ~/ 2;
        var yIndex = y * yStride + x;
        var uIndex = y2 * uStride + x2;
        var vIndex = y2 * vStride + x2;

        int yValue = yData[yIndex].toInt();
        int uValue = uData[uIndex].toInt();
        int vValue = vData[vIndex].toInt();

        // YUV to RGB conversion
        int r = (yValue + 1.13983 * (vValue - 128)).toInt();
        int g = (yValue - 0.39465 * (uValue - 128) - 0.58060 * (vValue - 128)).toInt();
        int b = (yValue + 2.03211 * (uValue - 128)).toInt();

        // Clamp the values to the range [0, 255]
        r = r.clamp(0, 255);
        g = g.clamp(0, 255);
        b = b.clamp(0, 255);
        
        img.setPixelRgb(x, y, r, g, b);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah that's going to storage...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the File(filePath).writeAsBytesSync is only for testing purpose !!!  this is why we callOpenFile.open(filePath) to check if image is correct ! in production code the last two line are removed and we call directly the tflite model from img object

Comment: does that mean that *even in production* you encode your image to JPEG only for that library to decode it? you really need to submit a feature request to that library. this is wasted CPU cycles.